# I need 2 denominational array sorted

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am working on a project that has a list of student name and numbers, for example

James Bloggs,1
Paul Jonson,43
Andt Peters,23

Once I have them in an array I then need them sorted.

What is the best way of going about this. Its not the sort Im stuck on its the referencing the names to the numbers. I would have thought if I do a 2 denominational array only one would be sorted.

Any help would be great,

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you stuck on attempting this?

Comment: The best way would be to create a POJO class of a student with fields `name` and `number` and use a `List` collection to hold all students. Then use built in `Collections.sort()` method on this list. Do not forget to implement necessary `Comparator`

Comment: Really im looking for the best approach. I have used a standard array, but unsure if a 2 denominational would be the way to go.

Comment: You are probably getting downvoted because the question is missing some key details. Don't get discouraged SO takes a while to get used to. I don't understand what the data actually represents. What are the numbers? Is there a 1-1 relationship between a name and a number? How is this sorted? If there is a 1-1 relationship you can encapsulate the name and number as a class and use a Map with the name or number for the key (whichever needs sorting) But either way you need to elaborate

Comment: Thanks for this @IvanPronin - have you any example code - this must be a common issue (I would have thought).

Comment: They are student name and number. Each student has a number that does not change.

Comment: And how are they sorted? By name? By number?

Comment: By number.. Sorry guys looks like I did not explain very well.

Comment: You'd better start with [Collections tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/intro/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I just realized this question was asking about a 2-dimensional array and my answer doesn't directly deal with that. I am skeptical that arrays should be involved at all. Arrays are usually for dealing with primitive data, and maybe if you are coming from a C background you'd think they'd be the natural thing to use. If you really honestly have to use arrays then this probably isn't the way to go.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html

```
public void foo(){

    // Use a TreeMap. It will sort keys on insertion.
    Map<Integer,String> nameByNumber = new TreeMap<>();
    nameByNumber.put(1, "James Boggs");
    // etc. put all the entries in however you need to
    List<Integer> sortedNumbers = personByNumber.getKeys();
    List<String> namesSortedByNumber = personByNumber.getNames();

}
```

If you need it to be more organized and complex, you can encapsulate the name and number into a Class with a name and number property. Then you'd still use the number as the key, but you'd have the full class as the value. Do this if you need to have more than just a name, like last name, first name, address, etc.